# Php Mysql multisearch functionality

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, join

The issues is finding a particular businesses based on multi categories. Following are my mysql tables:

business_tbl:

```
id | business_name | cat_id | cat2_id | cat3_id | sub_cat_id | sub_cat2_id | sub_cat3_id
1       bz1            1      2          3         1001          2001         3001
2       bz2            1      2          3         1002          2002         3002
3       bz3            1      2          3         1003          2003         3003
```

business_categories_tbl:

```
id | cat_name
 1     food
 2     restaurants
 3     wine
```

business_sub_categories_tbl:

```
b_sub_cat_id | b_sub_cat_name | b_maincat_id
 1001             donuts          1
 1002              xx             1
 2001             steakhouse      2
 2001              yy             2
 3001            white            3
 3002             zz              3
```

How can i find a particular business name based on multi category search? For example how the mysql query need to be so that it can search through all category ie `cat_id, cat2_id , cat3_id, sub_cat_id ,sub_cat2_id and sub_cat3_id` and return business_name if a match is found. My current query perform only 1 cat_id and 1 sub_cat_id search since joining multi categories not returning anything.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your post i try to build below query. Just try it:

```
select business_name  from  business_tbl where '1002' IN (cat_id, cat2_id , cat3_id, sub_cat_id ,sub_cat2_id, sub_cat3_id)
```

Comment: nope it's not works this way, the issues is join with other tables and do search

Comment: i need to search based on keywords that is available on business_categories_tbl and business_sub_categories_tbl and return business_id that match it. So there will be multiple joins